# Which planets have Paraffinium deposits to extract?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Which planets have Paraffinium deposits to extract?

I sold some ores and I don't remember which planet I managed to extract that element from.

Comment: It's cheap ([62](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Paraffinium) credits) mineral compared to e.g. activated indium ([949](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Activated_Indium)). Instead of searching for a planet, consider to just hop over stations to buy it from either of two trading terminals there or from ships on stations. It would be sold in big amounts (3-4k), will save you time spend while digging for it, unless you need deposit for a production cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the planets you've discovered are detailed in the discovery tab of the menu, including the resources that may be found there. Generally, Paraffinium is found on tropical planets.

Comment: [Here](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Biome_-_Lush) is reference to such planets on the wiki. Btw, not all resources are shown in discovery, it would be nice if you add a screenshot or something to suppliment your answer.

Comment: Actually, there is Guide page ([here](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/WQSA7ZiNOeHzUQ7TgdYpyFlh5vg=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x0/filters:focal(0x0:1920x1080):no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/11907501/nmsn_find__0002_Layer_2.jpg) is example) which lists all elements and shows where it can be found.